# Display Totals on Sharepoint 2010 list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list of items. For one of the views of that list I would like to display the total number of items at the top of the view. I click modify view and go to the "totals" section.

[image]

I save the view. However, when I open the view there are no totals to be seen.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get a count of the items to be displayed?

Update:
Just for fun I added a test column of type number to my list. I then went into the view and chose to display that column. I went to the totals section and chose "SUM" for that test number column. I saved it and went back to the view and the sum for that column didn't display either. Is there some setting that is just turning off the display of the summary row?

Comment: Something seems to be stopping all column totals from showing. I can't see counts, sums, etc. Is this a setting somewhere???

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to sum all the IDs values, this is not what you need to do. The total section is meant to do the calculation on the specified columns' values not on list items.

To do so, you can refer to this [LINK](http://sharepointlogics.com/2010/03/total-count-of-items-in-list-in.html).

---

Comment: Well is says "Count" as the total type. I would assume that would mean that it would count all the items and display the total. What else could "Count" possibly mean?

Comment: As far as I know, "Count" means doing the sum on the column values, not counting how many elements you have in your lists. I guess it didn't display anything in your case because SharePoint doesn't make a count operation on the "ID" column. You can refer to the link above, it could help  you.

Comment: No, Count is **not** the same as Sum. On SharePoint Online Count does exactly what OP expects. I don't have a SP2010 environment to test

Comment: -1 Count does just what it says, count the number of items. You can use it on a column of type text if you want.